# cannot load Json data via reflection

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

I have a data stored in Json. I can dynamically create the datatable columns but when i load the data, its not loaded.

```
  dt = new DataTable();
             Type firstType =new  TickerData().GetType();
           foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in firstType.GetProperties())
             {
                 dt.Columns.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
             }

            foreach (string file in filePaths)
            {

                TickerData td=getSymbolJson(file);


                DataRow newrow =dt.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in td.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    newrow[propertyInfo.Name] = propertyInfo.GetValue(td, null);
                }
                dt.ImportRow(newrow);

            }
```

I am missing something. Can you spot it? The data is there in the json. i can track it in visual studio

newrow has the data as you can see from the watch window
[image]

But the dataset visualizer shows no data for the datatable.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use
  dt.Rows.Add(newrow);
instead of 
 dt.ImportRow(newrow);